# reallocating the position of UINavigationbar ? Some Mismatch

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Can anyone please specify that how can we reallocate the position of UINavigationbar ?

Please go through the below link:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YibnNbicD1o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIToolbar could be created and placed where you want with Interface Builder or adjusted in code with the frame property. Not to be confounded with the UINavigationController top bar which is always on top... Good luck Tariq!